# Regexp oracle SQL

Tags: oracle

how can I check if string contains fixed number of numbers(int) then fixed number of characters and then again fixed numbers.
I'm searching only for 9 numbers 2 latter's and then 4 numbers everything else is FALSE for me.
From what I understand the best way to do it is with reg exp but can't set it up.

Comment: Need sample strings input (good and bad)  to show you how.

Comment: Nothing needs to be setup, the functions are avalable unless you have a very old version of Oracle.  See https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/B14251_01/adfns_regexp.htm, you could use regexp_like.

Comment: 123456789gm9876 good                                          372737373ddd123 bad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`regexp_like` might help.

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select '123456789gm9876' from dual union all
  3     select '372737373ddd123' from dual
  4    )
  5  select
  6    col,
  7    case when regexp_like(col, '^[[:digit:]]{9}[[:alpha:]]{2}[[:digit:]]{4}$') then 'good'
  8         else 'bad'
  9    end result
 10  from test;

COL             RESULT
--------------- ------
123456789gm9876 good
372737373ddd123 bad

SQL>
```

Comment: Looks like it should work but it doesn't could it be because there are upper case? 123456789GM9876

Comment: Well, it *works* on test case you provided (as demonstrated). If it should be case-insensitive, add the `i` parameter, e.g. `regexp_like(col, 'whatever', 'i')`

Comment: Yeah my bad fornthat example but when I put that 'i' it shows me some menu with "enter blinds" asking me to apply alpha and digits

Comment: Huh, I wouldn't know what it means. Which tool do you use? `'i'` causes *nothing* when I run such a code ...